# Submit button won't clear form field like enter does

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I originally coded my rails app to not have a submit button, but now I want to use enter OR a submit button. My submit button sends the data to my backend, but it doesn't clear the `textfield`.

Form:

```
<%= form_for message, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, data: {textarea: "message"}, placeholder: 'Tap the location to send your current location, or tap here to chat.', required: "required" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :groupchat_id, value: @groupchat.id %>
  <%= f.submit "", class: "send_icon", data: {send: "message"} %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    message = Message.new(message_params)
    message.user = current_user
    if message.save
      ActionCable.server.broadcast "messages_#{message.groupchat_id}_channel",
        message: message.content,
        user: message.user.name
      head :ok
    end
  end

  private

    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:content, :groupchat_id)
    end
end
```

JavaScript to clear form when pressing enter:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  submitNewMessage();
  $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight);
});

function submitNewMessage(){
  $('textarea#message_content').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('[data-send="message"]').click();
        $('[data-textarea="message"]').val("");
        return false;
     }
  });
}
```

How do I make it so the submit button clears the text area `#message_content`

Comment: Did u tried $("form").reset()  ?

Comment: Won't that prevent the form from being submitted?

Comment: after submit just call it. I will reset form, but it wont prevent form from submitting. Read doc